# Possible disadvantages of using cookieless forms authentication ticket in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, cookieless

If I use

```
<authentication mode="Forms">

  <forms

  cookieless="UseUri"

  slidingExpiration="true"

  timeout="60"

  />

</authentication>
```

Once you have made this change.When visiting as an anonymous user, the URLs will look exactly like they did before. For example, when visiting Default.aspx page my browser's address bar shows the following URL:

```
http://localhost:2448/default.aspx
```

However, upon logging in, the forms authentication ticket is embedded into the URL. For example, after visiting the login page and logging in as Sam, I am returned to the Default.aspx page, but the URL this time is:

```
http://localhost:2448/(F(jaIOIDTJxIr12xYS-VVgkqKCVAuIoW30Bu0diWi6flQC-FyMaLXJfow_Vd9GZkB2Cv-rfezq0gKadKX0YPZCkA2))/default.aspx
```

**Note:** cookieless authentication tickets are more prone to replay attacks since the authentication ticket is embedded directly in the URL. Imagine a user who visits a website, logs in, and then pastes the URL in an email to a colleague. If the colleague clicks on that link before the expiry is reached, they will be logged in as the user who sent the email!

This is one possible drawback if I use cookieless authentication ,I am interested in knowing   other possible drawbacks of this approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disadvantages:

1. limited amount of data that can be stored in the URL (especially in mobile and Windows 2003 platform)
2. Cookie replay attack (that you already mentioned) - can be avoided using ssl, and limited using timeout.
3. Your URL looks long and not "neat".

Comment: valuable point that limited amount of data can be stored in the URL , worth noting